# Finding the name of the Control attached to a element in CanJs

Tags: jquery, javascriptmvc, canjs, canjs-control

I am using Canjs to build my Web application . Now i have a issue while i am working on it.

The controllers get changed on a Single HTML element and the controllers that got attached to that particular element does not get destroyed when the new controller gets attached. So i decided to destroy all the controllers attached to that before I attach something else to it.

I am left with two queries

1. How do i find the attached controllers on a particular element ? as .controller() doesn't work
2. How do i call the destroy?

Please help me  Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [can.Control.plugin](http://canjs.us/#plugins-can_control_plugin) plugin it should be possible to access all the controls on an element by calling `$(element).controls()`.

Comment: but how do i extract the constructor name?

Comment: What do you mean? Depends on how you initialize it. `var Construct = can.Construct({}, {})` it doesn't have a name. If you are creating it with `can.Construct(`My.Name`, {}, {})` the `instance.constructor.fullName` property will be `My.Name`.

Comment: @Daff: $(element).controls() is not working for me. what would be the reasons for happening this?